# Requirements for random variables to be distributed identically

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, variance

If two random variables have the same expected value and the same variance, are they distributed identically? If not, how can we test if two random variables are identically distrubuted?

Many thanks in advance

Rolandos

Comment: "If two random variables have the same expected value and the same variance, are they distributed identically" Not necessarily. Please tell us what do you know about the variables.

Comment: Depending on the values they can take, one might make a best guess that they are from the same distribution. For example on $(-\infty,\infty)$ with only the mean and variance specified the maximum entropy guess is they are normally distributed variables, which will give them the same "best guess" distribution. But in general, the distributions could be quite different if one was to consider the higher, possibly infinite number of moments.

Comment: You can always find a Gaussian with a given mean and variance. Are all random variables Gaussian?

Answer (score 0):

No. If the 2 random variables with equal mean and variance may not have equal PDF. Consider for example:$$X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$$and$$Y\sim U(\mu -\sigma\sqrt 3,\mu +\sigma\sqrt 3)$$where $\sigma>0$ is the mean deviation.

One standard way way to check whether two random variables are identically distributed if their [Moment Generating Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function)s are equal, i.e.:$$E\{e^{Xt}\}=E\{e^{Yt}\}$$